# Scroll event performance when scrolling with scrollbar vs. wheel vs. swipe

Tags: javascript, scroll, html5-canvas

I'm making a simple website, that doesn't have to be super fast and performant, I'm only focused on some nice design elements. One of those design elements is blur that is applied to statically positioned background "under" some containers, that move when scrolling. [This example](http://kulikov.ml) should be self-explanatory. *(I hope it's OK to share the website itself. It's just a personal website, no advertisement intended.)*

This could be done with CSS filters and some moving `background-position` on the containers. However, the background is not an image but a canvas element. (For now, it's just an image redrawn into the canvas, but it will be generated algorithmically.) **So my approach is:** The blurred containers contain a canvas as their background and the content of the background canvas is redrawn with a filter applied on every scroll and resize event. As I said, this doesn't have to be fast and probably no other complex computations will be performed on the client-side, but a smooth user experience is important.

(If needed, I will provide relevant parts of the code.)

**My question is:** I noticed, that when scrolling with a scrollbar, it renders very smoothly, but when scrolling with a mouse wheel it probably just can't redraw the background fast enough and it looks as if the blurred background falls a bit behind. When swiping on a touch screen, it gets even worse and the blurred background is always behind the actual background. The fact that it's able to keep up when scrolling with a scrollbar makes me think that the problem is not with the canvas redrawing approach but with handling the events. Is there any way to handle the scroll event in such a way, that the performance will always be as good as when scrolling with a scrollbar? Maybe it's not even about performance, but rather that mouse wheel and swipe scrolling don't trigger the event as frequently, which causes these "gaps" when the canvas isn't being redrawn? If so, I should probably implement the redrawing in such a way, that it accounts for the delta of the scroll event and just draws the blurred background several times in between the events.

Comment: debouncing / throttling : https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/
and maybe you can cache some variables:
https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a
I encounter similar issue when it comes to 'caculate positions before redrawing images'.
If it doesn't have to correspond background image, things would be more easy.
Last, you can observe performance by chrome dev tool `performance` tab > record > scroll the website or do something > stop > check js file in `source` tab to see how long some lines take.

Comment: Thanks. Those optimizations target exactly the kind of stuff I do in my code - a bunch of event handlers and a lot of these layout related functions. I will try that out and update with the results.